# Fredholm equation for non-relativistic scattering

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

I came across another interesting integral equations problem:

Consider the integral equation (inspired by non-relativistic scattering of an electron):

$\phi(x)=exp(ikx)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{exp(ik|x-t|)}{2ik}V(t)\phi(t)$, where $\phi(x)$ represents the wave function of the single particle.

I am assuming $V,\phi$ are $L^2$ functions and $k$ is complex, $V$ is a known function

**PROBLEM**:

I want to compute the Taylor series for $D(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}c_n\lambda_ n$

and  ${D(x,t;\lambda)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}B_n(x,t)\lambda_n$

where $B_0(x,t)=K(x,t)$, $B_n(x,t)=c_nK(x,t)-n\int_{a}^{b}K(x,s)B_{n-1}(s,t)ds$

$c_n=\int_{a}^{b}B_n(t,t)dt$, with $c_0=1$.

**WORK**

I tried tracing through the formula, but this doesn't work, as the formula is for finite domains.

Comment: Is $K(x,t) = \frac{\exp(ik|x−t|)}{2ik}$, as you did not define it ? What is $\lambda_n$? What are $a,b$?

Comment: I also do not see how $\phi$ relates to all under "PROBLEM".